# Is Google Sites outdated?

Tags: google-sites

I'm looking into creating a small collaborative wiki/intranet site for my company. About 10 people will be using it. It will mainly contain a FAQ section, getting started, company's best practices and maybe a bit of news on projects. Google sites seems to perfectly fit the bill, as the company uses Google products quite a bit (calendar, mail, docs). Setup is very fast, and has most of the features I need (have not found syntax highlighting though which is a shame).

However, the more I document myself on the subject, the more I'm under the impression this seems to be an outdated solution.

- There doesn't seem to be many resources on the subject (look for questions in SO)
- [Google gadget](http://www.google.com/gadgets/directory?synd=open) site is hideous, content is average, and links are broken clicking on "Add to website"
- Can't seem to find many useful gadgets (like syntax highlighting)
- [Presentation video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fD-4FRTzxkI) is from 2008

I have no experience in creating a Google site, so considering I'm starting from scratch, should I be looking into a different "site building" solution or am I just trippin' ?

Comment: would be nice to know why you downvoted

Answer (score 3):

Google sites is still supported, but that doesn't mean it's good.  It's useful for internal information sites as you can add permissions to sites based on Google users (set a site to "everyone in your enterprise"), but if you want to beyond basic skinning with CSS and simple content, you pretty much have to be a Google code junky.